# Excel VBA Sort and Group Paths into Folders

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, hyperlink, filenames

The code below:

```
Sub cmdList()
Dim sPath   As String
Dim fOut    As Variant
Dim r       As Integer
Dim Cell As Range

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) '.Title = "Select directory"
    .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
    sPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
Cells(4, 1) = sPath
fOut = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec("cmd /c dir """ & sPath & """ /a:-h-s /b /s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine) 'List all

r = 5: Range(r & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
Cells(r, 2).Resize(UBound(fOut), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(fOut)
End Sub
```

After a sort produces this output:

[image: Output]

I would then like to convert those paths to hyperlinks, and group based on the folder names. The output would look like this:

[image: Grouped output]

I tried using the File System Object, but it was too slow over a network. The shell script was much faster. I need help with the rest of it!

Thanks, all.

Comment: Did you try [Powerquery](https://trumpexcel.com/list-file-names-power-query/)?

Comment: I could do it with PowerQuery, but the end game is to automate everything with a macro for the end user who is not so excel-savvy.

Comment: What specifically do you not know how to do?  Seems like you know the steps you need to take if you already got to the second screenshot.

Comment: The second screenshot was created by manually grouping the files. I would like a macro to do it.